# Pandas: Idiomatic method for indexing an element that is a certain position away from a known label?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm looking for a simple idiomatic way to index into an element that I don't know its label or position) that is a certain position away from a known element (an element that I know the label of).

I read most of the Pandas docs at [Selecting and Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html). Still couldn't find the answer.

I was hoping to be able to do something like:

`df.loc['some known label' + 3]`
To get the row that is 3 elements below some known label.

Or perhaps use it with slicing:
`df.loc['some known label' - 3 : 'some other know label' + 5]`

so from the data frame below:

```
In [44]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), index=list('abcdef'), columns=list('ABCD')) 

In [45]: df1
Out[45]: 
          A         B         C         D
a  0.132003 -0.827317 -0.076467 -1.187678
b  1.130127 -1.436737 -1.413681  1.607920
c  1.024180  0.569605  0.875906 -2.211372
d  0.974466 -2.006747 -0.410001 -0.078638
e  0.545952 -1.219217 -1.226825  0.769804
f -1.281247 -0.727707 -0.121306 -0.097883
```

I would like to do something like  `df.loc['c' + 2]`

and get:

```
          A         B         C         D
e  0.545952 -1.219217 -1.226825  0.769804
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: df1.iloc[df1.index.get_loc('c') + 2] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Emma suggests use `get_loc` to get the the integer location of the index label, however, use double brackets to get results as a dataframe, otherwise you'll get a series instead:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), index=list('abcdef'), columns=list('ABCD')) 
df1.iloc[[df1.index.get_loc('c')+2]]
```

Output:

```
          A         B         C         D
e -1.393951 -0.725751 -1.063748 -0.271371
```